# how to get array of values in done callback for $.when.apply($, promises)

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I have an array of promises:
var promises = [];
where each promises resolve function is passed a value:
deferredObj.resolve(someValue);

So in the end I need to do something when all the promises are resolved and the done function is executed.

**AJS.$.when.apply(AJS.$, promises).done(function(arrayOfValues){**

}

question is I cant get the resolved values above because that isn't filled up (it only has the value obtained from the first resolve).

How can I get a variable number of values in the done function above?

Thanks

Comment: the then callback will have more than one argument passed in - arguments[0...n] ... why not use `Promise.all(promises).then(function(thisAcutallyIsAnArrayOfvalues){`

Comment: Thanks @Jaromanda X. Since yours was the first reply that correctly answered the question, please repost it as an answer so I can accept it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery passes the results as separate arguments.  You can use them this way if you have a known number of arguments or if you don't specifically need them in an array:

```
$.when.apply($, promises).done(function(r1, r2, r3, r4, r5) {
    // process various results here
});
```

If you want to get the arguments in an array, you have a couple options.

```
$.when.apply($, promises).done(function() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    // now all the arguments are in the args array
});
```

Or, in an appropriate ES6 environment, you can use the spread operator:

```
$.when.apply($, promises).done(function(...args) {
    // now all the arguments are in the args array
});
```

Or, in an ES6 promise environment or with a suitable Promise polyfill, you can just use `Promise.all()` which does something similar to `$.when()`, but accepts an array as its initial argument and puts the results into an array:

```
Promise.all(promises).done(function(arrayOfResults) {
    // process various results here
});
```